# Windows 10 EFI system partition on a wrong hard disk - possible to fix?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I have 3 separate physical hard disks in my PC, Windows 10 is installed on the first one. I want to replace the third one with something bigger, but the system does not boot if I unplug it. After some experimentation I found out that for whatever reason the EFI System Partition is installed on that disk, so I assume that is the reason. Obviously that can be rectified by unplugging everything except the first hard disk and doing a clean reinstall, but the times when I was enjoying reinstalling my OS are long gone. Is it possible to fix the situation, e. g. move/re-create the EFI partition on the first hard disk? Googling only gave me some results about repairing a broken EFI partition, but in my case it doesn't exist there in the first place.